# IF Else Condition for Timedelta Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following multi index data

```
               2002074266              2002074444
TimeStamp   Total       Freq       Total       Freq
HH:MM        Pc          Hz         Pc          Hz
06:50        3           10         7           13
06:55        4           11         8           14
07:00        5           12         9           15
08:55        6           13         1           12
09:00        7           13         3           13
```

I am trying to do an IF ELSE condition for the time range. The time interval is 5 minutes per line. IF a time range between 07:00 to 09:10 is missing any 5 minutes data (as the case in this example), the ELSE statement will run. I am not sure how to declare a time range for my IF ELSE.

This is my current code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Test.csv", header=[0,1], skiprows = 3, index_col=0)
df1 = df.loc[:,(slice(None), ['Total'])]
df2 = df1.iloc[1:,:] 
df2.index = pd.to_timedelta(df2.index + ':00')

if (df2.index == '07:00:00').any():
   print('Complete data')
else:
   print("Filling in progress")
   df2 = df2.resample('5min').ffill() 
   print('Missing data, forward filled')

df2.to_csv('Result.csv')
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need:

```
if (df2.loc['07:00:00':'09:10:00'].index.to_series().diff().iloc[1:] == '00:05:00').all():
    print('Complete data')
```

**Explanation**:

1. First filter range for check difference if necessary
2. Convert [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html), because [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) is not yet implemented for `TimedeltaIndex`
3. Remove first `NaN` by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html)
4. Compare by 5 minutes and check if [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html) `True`s

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Never expected the line to be written like this. Learnt something new. :)